# Flask: testing an AJAX call that requires a logged in user

Tags: jquery, ajax, unit-testing, flask, flask-login

I am trying to work with (and test) an AJAX call. I am not a pro, I hope I am using the terms correctly.

I have a Flask app that makes an AJAX call from a view that is accessible only to logged in users (using JQuery):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/_get_data",
    data: JSON.stringify({begin_date: begin_date,
                          end_date: end_date}, null, '\t'),
    contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response){
         // do something with the results
         }
    });
```

The end-point function needs to access the logged user data. Using Flask-Login this is stored in the current_user proxy (the function below is just for the example, I know the query can be done differently):

```
@app.route('/_get_data', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_data():
    param = request.get_json()
    # get data from the DB for the current user
    data = db.session.query(Orders).filter(Orders.customer_id == current_user.id).all()
    # ...
    # Do calculations on data and return the results
    # ...
    return jsonify(results = results)
```

I have two questions:

1. Is relying on Flask-Login current_user proxy a safe approach? Or would it be better to send the current_user id with the AJAX call, and query the DB for the user inside the get_data() function? With this second approach, however, it means to have the user id in clear in the ajax call.
2. From the view, the function get_data() responds properly. However, how to unit-test the get_data() function? The problem I am facing is to "pass" the current_user to the get_data() function. I am using pytest, and searching around I have found [solutions like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16238462/flask-unit-test-how-to-test-request-from-logged-in-user/16238537#16238537) the following:

.

```
app = create_app(DevConfig)
data = {"begin_date": "", "end_date": ""}
with app.test_client() as tester:
    with tester.session_transaction() as sess:
        sess['user_id'] = 1
        sess['_fresh'] = True
        response = tester.get('/_get_data',
                    content_type='application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                    headers={'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                             'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                    data=json.dumps(data))
```

but it does not work for me: the get_data() function gets an 'AnonymousUserMixin' object instead of a logged in user.

Sorry for my low-technical language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem in my second question. It was just a matter of indentation of the code within the `with` statement.
The correct version is, as described in [Can't Get Session Variables Set Up In Flask Unit Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35470357/cant-get-session-variables-set-up-in-flask-unit-test) (notice the identation of the `response`):

```
app = create_app(DevConfig)
data = {"begin_date": "", "end_date": ""}
with app.test_client() as tester:
    with tester.session_transaction() as sess:
        sess['user_id'] = 1
        sess['_fresh'] = True
    response = tester.get('/_get_data',
                content_type='application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                headers={'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                         'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                data=json.dumps(data))
```

My first question, however, still stands.